# Is this code for initializing an SD card in SPI mode correct?

Tags: c, arduino, sd-card, spi, atmega

I want to initialize an SD card manually from an Arduino Mega 2560 and read its contents.

I've read a lot of manuals explaining how to properly do it, as well as the Arduino SD library code, but I can't get it to work.

```c
uint8_t spi_byte(uint8_t byte) {
  SPDR = byte;
  asm volatile("nop");
  while(!(SPSR & B10000000));
  uint8_t response = SPDR;
  return response;
}

uint8_t sd_cmd(uint8_t cmd, uint32_t args) {
  if(cmd != 0x40) while(spi_byte(0xFF) != 0xFF);
  spi_byte(cmd);
  int8_t c;
  for(c = 3; c >= 0; --c) spi_byte(args >> (c << 3));
  uint8_t crc;
  if(cmd == 0x40) crc = 0x95;
  else if(cmd == 0x48) crc = 0x87;
  else crc = 0xFF;
  spi_byte(crc);
  uint8_t response;
  for(c = 16; ((response = spi_byte(0xFF)) & 0x80) && c; --c);
  /*if((cmd < 0x51) || (cmd > 0x59))*/ spi_byte(0xFF); //S
  return response;
}

void sd_init() {
  DDRB &= B11110000;
  PORTB |= B0001; //set CS pull-up resistor (just-in-case)
  DDRB |= B0001; //set CS to output
  PORTB |= B1000; //set MISO pull-up resistor (just-in-case)
  SPCR = B01010010; //no interrupt, MSB first, master, mode 0, fosc/64 (250 kHz)
  SPSR &= ~1; //clear SPI double speed
  DDRB |= B0110; //set SCK and MOSI to output
  delayMicroseconds(200000);
  uint8_t c;
  cli();
  for(c = 0; c < 10; ++c) spi_byte(0xFF); //synchronize clock
  clb(PORTB, 0); //set CS low
  uint8_t response;
  uint16_t timeout = 1024;
  while((response=sd_cmd(0x40, 0)) != 0x1) { //CMD0: reset card
    if((!response) || (response == 0xFF)) error(3); //we don't even have a card
    if(!--timeout) error(7); //timed out
  }
  if(sd_cmd(0x48, 0x1AA) != 1) error(1); //CMD8: make sure we are using SD v2
  for(c = 0; c < 4; ++c) spi_byte(0xFF);
  do {
    sd_cmd(0x77, 0); //CMD55: introduce application-specific command
    response = sd_cmd(0x69, 0x40000000); //ACMD41: initialize card
    if(!--timeout) error(8); //timed out
  } while(response != 0);

  sd_cmd(0x7A, 0); //CMD58: read OCR
  response = spi_byte(0xFF);
  if((response & B11000000) != B11000000) error(2); //make sure we are using SDHC
  for(c = 0; c < 3; ++c) spi_byte(0xFF);

  stb(PORTB, 0); //set CS high
  SPCR = B01010000; //fosc/4 (4 MHz)
  SPSR |= 1; //set SPI double speed (8 MHz)
  for(c = 0; c < 10; ++c) spi_byte(0xFF); //synchronize clock
  sei();
  return;
}

void sd_read(uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t block, uint8_t start2, uint8_t size2) {
  /*start2 and size2 are in 2 byte units, size2 = 0 means whole block (512 B)*/
  cli();
  block <<= 9; //S//D
  clb(PORTB, 0); //set CS low
  uint8_t response;
  if((response=sd_cmd(0x51, block))) { //CMD17: read single block
    Serial.begin(9600); //D
    Serial.println(response, HEX); //D
    error(10);
  }
  while(spi_byte(0xFF) != 0xFE) ; //TODO: timeout error 9
  uint8_t b = 0; uint8_t end = 0;
  do {
    if((b >= start2) && (!end)) {
      *(buffer++) = spi_byte(0xFF);
      *(buffer++) = spi_byte(0xFF);
      --size2;
      if(!size2) end = 1;
    }
    else {
      spi_byte(0xFF);
      spi_byte(0xFF);
    }
    ++b;
  } while(b); //repeat 256 times
  spi_byte(0xFF); spi_byte(0xFF); //two more bytes to close
  stb(PORTB, 0); //set CS high
  spi_byte(0xFF);
  sei();
  return;
}
```

Some days it works perfectly, other times it just locks up at initialization time, and finally right now I'm trying to read SD card contents and it just displays 0x55AA forever. I suspect that it is a hardware problem, but I'd like to rule out the possibility that my code might be wrong. Also, I don't know why I have to multiply reading address by 512. Being this an SDHC card, I would expect addresses to be in blocks, right?

Comment: It is recommended that you create some SPI clock cycles before and after you select the SD card. I´ve tested it without and with additional clock cycles with different cards and it works better when I do it.
You also can check my implementation for an SD card driver for XMega
https://gitlab.com/Kampi/avr/blob/master/source/Peripheral/SD/SD.c

Comment: _"...other times it just locks up at initialization time"_ probably because you have blocking code e.g. `while(spi_byte(0xFF) != 0xFF);` and `while(!(SPSR & B10000000));` ....I see this all too often with embedded systems new comers...learn state machines and never block

Comment: I used the CardInfo demo sketch with the appropriate port numbers and it initializes the SD card, but can't read it afterwards. So I think it must be a hardware problem. Either I have made a mistake when wiring, or the SD card reader is defective, or it's not getting enough power. Thank you anyway!